# Getting the slack variables from an SVM with SKlearn

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

A support vector machine learned on non-linearly separable data learns a slack variable for each datapoint. Is there any way to train the [SKlearn implementation of SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), and then get the slack variable for each datapoint from this?

I am asking in order to implement dSVM+, as described [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608009001130). This involves training an SVM and then using the slack variables as a 'deviation value', used as privileged information when training an SVM+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slack variable is $|t-y(x)|$, where $t\in\{-1,1\}$. The [`decision_function`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) gives $y(x)$, so you can just do `slack = abs(t-clf.decision_function([x]))`.